# How can I over-ride the click of each LI in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following UL:

```
   <ul class="xbreadcrumbs" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px">
<li><a href="someURL">A Crumb</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is being dynamically created by my javascript. How can I override the click for each LI that is inside of a UL called xbreadcrumbs in jQuery and have it do something instead of go to a new hyperlink?

Also, how can I get the behavior to be different for each li?

Updated:

```
$.each('.xbreadcrumbs li', function(){
        $(this).live('click',function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          console.log('clicked for each li');
        });
    });
```

Comment: By override do you mean prevent it from doing anything or having it fire a function?

Comment: To prevent the a element from triggering look at return false or preventDefault. To attach a jQeury click event to a dynamic element use the live() function.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation` should probably be `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live is part of the answer, the other part of the answer is that you need to use the event's `target` property to know which element was actually clicked.

```
$('.xbreadcrumbs li').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Clicked on element', e.target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the `ul` dynamically to the DOM you could subscribe to the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event of the inner `lis`:

```
$('.xbreadcrumbs li').click(function() {
    // do something when the li is clicked
});
```

Comment: how can I add a click to each individual li? each one will have some logic to do something different..

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function so that dynamically created elements get the event attached...

```
$("ul.xbreadcrumbs li").live("click", function() {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a live event:

```
$('.xbreadcrumbs li').live('click', function(){
    //override here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `</ul>` is being added dynamically it is best to use [$.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [$.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this:

```
$('.xbreadcrumbs li').live('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Clicked');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The click event is bound, but the it still takes me to the hyperlink. e.stopPropagation() doesnt seem to work in this case?

Comment: `stopPropagation()` doesn't stop the event's default action (navigation), you have to use `preventDefault()` or return false from the handler.

Comment: preventDefault() did the trick. I also realized while this gets the click for the li, how can I get EACH li? I'd like to print something different for each LI